# How to extract insights from facebook action dataset and covert all values into each column

Tags: json, pandas, dictionary, for-loop, facebook-graph-api

[Here is dataset as shown in below and I want to convert it into each data column with their values as](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1co8.png)

i want to append the values in columns and I tried this code

```
y = data['actions'].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace("'",'"'))
json.loads(y[0])
json.loads(y[1])
```

it gives output like as shown in below

```
[{'action_type': 'post_reaction', 'value': '2'},
 {'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '42'},
 {'action_type': 'comment', 'value': '1'},
 {'action_type': 'post_engagement', 'value': '45'},
 {'action_type': 'page_engagement', 'value': '45'},
 {'action_type': 'onsite_conversion.lead_grouped', 'value': '6'},
 {'action_type': 'leadgen_grouped', 'value': '6'},
 {'action_type': 'lead', 'value': '6'}]

[{'action_type': 'onsite_conversion.post_save', 'value': '1'},
 {'action_type': 'post_reaction', 'value': '4'},
 {'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '62'},
 {'action_type': 'post_engagement', 'value': '67'},
 {'action_type': 'page_engagement', 'value': '67'},
 {'action_type': 'onsite_conversion.lead_grouped', 'value': '6'},
 {'action_type': 'leadgen_grouped', 'value': '6'},
 {'action_type': 'lead', 'value': '6'}]
```

I want to create the dataframe that gives each action type as column and append their values in respective columns and if there is no value it appends zero like

```
| post_reaction| link click | comment |---------------------
| --------     | -----------|---------|
| 2            | 42         |1        |
|  4           | 62         |67       |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no lists in data use `ast.literal_eval` for converting first and then with list comprehension create `DataFrame`:

```
import ast

y = data['actions'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

df = pd.DataFrame([{z['action_type']:z['value'] for z in x} for x in y]).fillna(0)
```

If lists in data use only list comprehension:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame([{z['action_type']:z['value'] for z in x} for x in data['actions']])
        .fillna(0))
```

Comment: Thank you it works when there is no missing values in data["actions"],

I want all zeros if I get missing values in data['actions'],

Can you please suggest me what can i do

Comment: @ShubhamLondhe - `.fillna(0)` not replace `NaN`s to missing values?

Comment: @ShubhamLondhe - Are data in picture confidental?

Comment: when there is missing value in action_type it fill zero but i want to fill zero for all the action type when there is missing value in main dataframe i.e data["action"]

Comment: yes the data is confidential but if you want i will give you sample

Comment: @ShubhamLondhe - hmmm, it seems saome data related problem. So I ask if possible post file with 2 rows of data which failed.

Comment: @ShubhamLondhe - super, please then test example if failed in my solution.

Comment: when i remove missing values in main data frame your code works without any error

Comment: where to post files of these data, let me check

Comment: @dropbox, google docs, wetransfer... OK, please create sample data with 2 rows with problematic data, it means where replacement not working like need.

Comment: Please open this link you will get dataset https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UG5ol5RtP8PBRtOtJGIF31oosFmKHd1b/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=114985598979428864098&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: @ShubhamLondhe - requests for acces was sent

Comment: @ShubhamLondhe - are there only 2 rows with problematic data?

Comment: see there are 3 missing row i want just fill  zeros to each column

Comment: @ShubhamLondhe - I understand now.

Comment: @ShubhamLondhe - hmmm, I test it.

Comment: @ShubhamLondhe - I got solution, can you try `y = data['actions'].fillna('{}').apply(ast.literal_eval)` instead `y = data['actions'].apply(ast.literal_eval)` ? All another code is same.